# hover для картинки

Tags: css3

Как сделать такой эффект при наведении на картинку?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поставить лупу и сделать картинку синей?

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, я делал примерно то же самое, только неправильно псевдоклассы и псевдоэлементы прописывал

Comment: @РусланГлухов Добавил лупу*)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME мне оч. понравилось имя класса `bubu` :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В общий блок добавляются и картинка, и блок с полупрозрачным фоном (внутри него и можно разместить тот SVG с белой лупой). Хотя можно и на CSS сделать лупу)

```css
.block {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.layer {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 150, 255, 0.3);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.block:hover .layer {
  display: block;
}



.bubu { /* Лупа */
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; /* центрирование со всех сторон */
  width: 40px; height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
  font-size: 50px;
  padding-top: 18px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 3px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;
}
.bubu::after { /* её ручка */
  content: "";
  width: 5px; height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  bottom: -20px;
  right: -7px;
  transform: rotate(-40deg);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://gyazo.com/5e5d72d372a0ffa88dadb2da5ad479c4.png">
  <div class="layer">
    <div class="bubu">+</div>
  </div>
</div>
```